# Getting error when trying to put <tr> after map function in a table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to put Hi right after map function but I get this error message: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. I tried to put {} around map function but I got another error: Unexpected token, expected . Any idea how should I achieve this?

```
<tbody>
          {(typeof transfersIn.donation !== "undefined") ?
          transfersIn.donation.map((donation,index) => {
            totalCIDonation += donation.amount;
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td className="date">{Common.getDateFormat(donation.date)}</td>
                <td>{(typeof donation.items !== "undefined") ? (
                  donation.items.length > 1 ? (
                    donation.items.map((item,index) => (<p key={index}>{item.description}</p>))
                  ) : donation.items[0].description
                ) : null}</td>
                <td>{(typeof donation.items !== "undefined") ? (
                  donation.items.length > 1 ? (
                    donation.items.map((item,index) => (<p key={index}>{item.details}</p>))
                  ) : donation.items[0].details
                ) : null}</td>
                <td className="dollars">{Common.getDollarFormat(donation.amount)}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          })<tr><td>Hi</td></tr>:(
            <tr>
              <td colSpan="4">No donations into your {accountLabel.Brokerage} occurred in this period.</td>
            </tr>
          )}
</tbody>
```

Comment: What is the error? And please do give your original code.

Comment: Fixed language and text layout

Comment: This is the error message: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
<tbody>
 {!!x && <tr colSpan="2"><td>Hi</td></tr>}
 {(typeof x !== "undefined") ?
   x.map((donation,index) => {
   y ++;
   return (
    <tr key={index}>
     <td>Hi</td>
     <td>Hi</td>
    </tr>
   )
 }) :
 {!!x && <tr colSpan="2"><td>Hi</td></tr>}
```

Comment: I want to put <tr> tag right after map function and before : because I want to have this row of table when x is not undefined.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer, If `x` is undefined, It will render the `<tr>` tag before and after the map function.